# interpolating 3D data in matlab

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I have a sample of data in the format `x y z vx vy vz`, describing the velocity components `vx`, `vy` and `vz` at a given position `x`, `y` and `z`. As a simple test, say the data has the following format (i.e., the position is *not uniform*):

```
x = rand(1,10);
y = rand(1,10);
z = rand(1,10);

vx = rand(1,10);
vy = rand(1,10);
vz = rand(1,10);
```

I would like the interpolate each of the velocity components and find them at a general position `x0`, `y0` and `z0`. Which function in Matlab can I use for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `TriScatteredInterp` (older versions of Matlab) or `scatteredInterpolant` (latest versions of Matlab) on each component:

```
% Define data:
x = rand(1,10)';
y = rand(1,10)';
z = rand(1,10)';

vx = rand(1,10)';
vy = rand(1,10)';
vz = rand(1,10)';

% Construct interpolant objects:
Fx = TriScatteredInterp(x,y,z,vx);
Fy = TriScatteredInterp(x,y,z,vy);
Fz = TriScatteredInterp(x,y,z,vz);

% Evaluate at desired point (here [0.5, 0.6, 0.7])
vx_interp = Fx([0.5, 0.6, 0.7])
vy_interp = Fy([0.5, 0.6, 0.7])
vz_interp = Fz([0.5, 0.6, 0.7])
```

Comment: Thanks. The documentation says that `scatteredInterpolant` is preferred over `TriScatteredInterp`. I'm just worried about the continuity and smoothness, but I guess I will have to test it...

Comment: `scatteredInterpolant` is continuous over a _convex_ polygon of your input points...good luck.

Comment: Looks like you need 2012 or maybe 2013  (or later) versions.

Comment: I can use both functions as I have R2015b -- I'm just wondering which one is best to use, `scatteredInterpolant` or `TriScatteredInterp`?

Comment: `scatteredInterpolant` obviously :-)